# Does Linkedin allow to thirdparty tools to crawl the info about mention/hashtag?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am checking for brand monitoring tools in order to get results for the mentions/hashtags of my brand on the web and on social media.
Can these tool crawl Linkedin data in order to get results for this kind of query?
thanks

Comment: This question may not fit SO good question recommendations. You might want to demonstrate what you tried to learn and do, before someone can give an answer.

Comment: Linkedin API doesn't allow crawl of Linkedin data to 3rd party tools and if I connect to Linkedin I will only be able to show the results in my feed but not a mention in somebody else feed.